# Makefile: No rule to make target. Stop

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

i'm new to `Makefile`. I've to write a Makefile to build a shared libary.

```
CC =g++
CFLAGS =-fPIC -Wall -Wextra -c
LDFLAGS =-shared
RM =rm -rf
TARGET_LIB =lib/Automat.so

SRC_DIR =src/
LIB_DIR =lib/
DEP_DIR =dep/

SRCS=IFSM.h IState.h ITransition.h FSM.h State.h Transition.h Wildcard.h PrimeTransition.h SingleTransition.h Exception.h Type.h Error.h
OBJS=$(SRCS:.h=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET_LIB)

$(TARGET_LIB): $(SRC_DIR)$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(SRC_DIR)$(SRCS:.h=.d):%.d:$(SRC_DIR)%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< > $(DEP_DIR)$@

include $(SRCS:.h=.d)
```

My problem is that i get the error

> No rule to make target `IFSM.d'.  Stop.

If i remove to file from `SRCS` the problem occurs with `IState.d`. All other .d files where builded correct (11 of 12).

All files exists and they are written correct (case-sensitiv).

I rly don't know where the error could be and i was searching for 2 hours now.

Any help would be great.

Best regards
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including

```
$(SRCS:.h=.d)
```

that is, files called `whatever.d` in the local directory; but you have a rule to make

```
$(SRC_DIR)$(SRCS:.h=.d)
```

that is, files called `src/whatever.d`.

You need to decide where these files should live, and make both rules match.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using tabs for indentation. Such mysterious failures are usually caused by using spaces, which are not supported by make.

Comment: This answer should be a comment. Also Make will complain about using spaces for indentation in most cases.